# How to create new rows dependent on other rows

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
sp0000001-mRNA-1    
sp0000005-mRNA-1    GO:0003723
sp0000006-mRNA-1    GO:0016021
sp0000007-mRNA-1    GO:0003700|GO:0006355|GO:0043565
```

The aim would be to generate new rows for GO ids which were separated by `|`. From the above example it would lead to 2 more rows

```
sp0000001-mRNA-1    
sp0000005-mRNA-1    GO:0003723
sp0000006-mRNA-1    GO:0016021
sp0000007-mRNA-1    GO:0003700
sp0000007-mRNA-1    GO:0006355
sp0000007-mRNA-1    GO:0043565
```

How is it possible to do it R?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(df, "V2", "|", "long")`

Comment: `tidyr::separate_rows`

Comment: `tidyr::unnest`

Comment: is there any performance difference between the above solutions?